# jQuery selector from a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/sr3q00nz/)**

```
var $select = $('select');

$select.on('change', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var modifier = value.split('_')[0];
    var target = modifier + '_target';

    console.log(target);

    $('div').filter(target).addClass('active');

});
```

If you open console and select any option from the `select`, you'll see that the text that is thrown to the console is legit (as I want to select `modifier1_target` depending on the selected option).

However, I can not make a jQuery selector out of this, so as the `div` is selected and applied an `active` class.

I tried `$(el).attr('class', target)` but it didn't work surely.

I am running out of ideas where am I wrong here?

Comment: Specify a ***.*** before the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell jQuery that it's a class you're looking for `('.' + target)`:

```
$('div').filter('.' + target).addClass('active');
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sr3q00nz/1/)

Comment: or: `$('div.'+target).addClass('active');`

Comment: @michael damn, same time but I posted a comment. +1. :D

Comment: I've been faster than your comment, too :D @Script47